# Randows steps in any 4 directon

Tags: combinatorics

> Starting from the origin a person takes 1 random step in any of one
> directions up down left or right . He takes 3 more steps of equal
> length in the same random manner .
>
> 1. How many different routes can he take ?
> 2. How many of the different routes will bring him back to the origin?
>
> Ans for first part: 256
> Ans for second part: "depends on his initial route"

This question and answer is taken from [this website](http://goo.gl/q0xDGb)

(1)For first part, the above site  gives answer as $4*4*4*4=256$. How we can apply multiplication like this? Also, different routes can lead to same place. So I think, 256 paths, even if it is true, means paths in different directions (but may or may not lead to same place). Is my understanding right?

(2) For the second part, the above site  gives "This depends on his initial route". How this can be true. From any path, there can be infinite return paths right? (if we take 4 or more steps to return). Is my understanding right?

Comment: For (1), it is $4^4$, $4$ possible moves to the power of number of moves. As you said, these are the number of different "routes" NOT "destinations" which are two different things.

Comment: For (2), I believe the person who wrote the response misunderstood the question. The question is clearly asking about the number of routes out of the $256$ will bring him to the origin, while that person is talking about $4$ more moves after the first $4$.

Comment: However, if we assume that there is no misunderstanding, he is right, if your first $4$ moves were UP, there is only one return path which is $4$ downs. Assuming we only need to return in only $4$ other moves.